# Enable Multi Select & Event Select Datatable At The Same Initialising Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

can someone tell me how to enable `multi select` and enable `event select` at the same initialising `datatables`

i don't have problem to enable `multi select` with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
       select: {
         style: 'multi'
       }
    });
});
```

but `select` event will not fired with only that code 
i need to make that code become like this to fired `select` event datatable

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    select: true
} );
```

i already try with code like this

```
"select": true {
   "style": 'multi'
 }

"select": {
   "select" : true,
   "style": 'multi'
}

"select" : {"style": 'multi', true}

"select": {"style": 'multi'},
"select" : true
```

and some other code but none of them working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should working by using this only.

```
  select: {
     'style': 'multi'
  }
```

But, make sure you already included the select extension into your datatables source, choose what extensions you want to be included https://datatables.net/download/

See example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/09achxyo/